# Gurobi MVar: Accessing Attributes always throws a GurobiError

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to use Gurobi's `MVar` class.

```py
import gurobipy as gp

m = gp.Model()
v = m.addMVar((10,))
v.lb  # raises GurobiError, index out of range...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call

```py
m.update()
```

before accessing `lb`.